# What is the operation of assigning a class to a constant called? Swift, Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, delegates, protocols

I'm trying to figure out the delegate and the protocol and studying the tutorial. It has the following code:

```
class SelectTimeViewController: UIViewController, PopupDelegate{
...
 let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "DatePopupViewController", bundle: nil) 
 let popup = sb.instantiateInitialViewController() as! DatePopupViewController          
 popup.delegate = self
…
}
```

What does this line in the code mean?

```
let popup = sb.instantiateInitialViewController() as! DatePopupViewController
```

I understand that here we are creating a popup constant and assigning something to it, which is then cast to the DatePopupViewController class.

But what does this mean more generally?

1. Are we create an instance of the DatePopupViewController class?
2. Are we assign any value from the DatePopupViewController class to the let popup?
3. Are we create a copy of the DatePopupViewController class?

Update:
About #1.

Usually, when we create an instance of a class, we use the following syntax:

```
constant (or variable) = ClassName (initializer)
```

For example:

```
var item = Item(name: "Car")
```

In this case, the syntax is different. We don't have an initializer (parentheses).

```
let popup = ... DatePopupViewController
```

Can we say in this case that an instance of the class has been created here?

Comment: *we are .... assigning something...*. No, not something, *we are assigning* the object in the storyboard which the entry point (the arrow) points to. As the object can be any subclass of `UIViewController` you have to cast the type, so 1.

Comment: Thank you for your response. You wrote - "we are assigning the object". Are we creating a copy of the object?

Answer (score 1):

[Your storyboard has one or more scenes.](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/11.4/#/dev62c993289) Each scene is managed by a [view controller](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller). Usually you'll create a custom `UIViewController` subclass for each scene. In the storyboard editor, for each scene, [you type in the name of that custom class.](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/11.4/#/dev87f4911e2)

One of the scenes in the storyboard can marked as the “initial scene”. `UIStoryboard` has a method, [`instantiateInitialViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboard/1616213-instantiateinitialviewcontroller#), that loads that scene from the storyboard.

But there are lots and lots of storyboards in the world, and they use lots and lots of different custom `UIViewController` subclasses for their scenes. You might even have multiple storyboards in a single app, each with an initial scene that uses a different custom subclass.

There is no way, at compile-time, for `UIStoryboard` to know what class the `instantiateInitialViewController` is going to load. All it knows at compile-time is that it's going to load a `UIViewController`, or a subclass of `UIViewController`. So `instantiateInitialViewController` is declared to return `UIViewController`.

But when you're writing your code, you usually do know what specific subclass it's going to load, and often you want to do things that depend on the subclass. In the code you posted, you're setting a property named `delegate`, which is a property specific to `DatePopupViewController`—it is not a property of `UIViewController`.

In order to access that `delegate` property, you need to tell Swift what you know that Swift doesn't already know. You need to tell Swift that you're loading a `DatePopupViewController`. You do that using syntax called a [“cast”](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html):

```
let popup = sb.instantiateInitialViewController() as! DatePopupViewController 
↑   ↑       ↑  ↑                                  ↑   ↑
|   |       |  This method returns a              |   The subclass you know
|   |       |  UIViewController object. It        |   you're loading.
|   |       |  might be (and usually is) a        |
|   |       |  subclass of UIViewController.      The cast operator.
|   |       |                                     The ! means the program
|   |       This variable references              will crash if the
|   |       a UIStoryboard object,                loaded object is not
|   |       which represents a                    an instance of
|   |       storyboard at runtime.                DatePopupViewController.
|   |
|   This variable gets bound to the
|   newly-loaded DatePopupViewController.
|
This says that the popup variable cannot
be changed to point at a different
instance of DatePopupViewController.
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. I understand that there can be several scenes and each scene has its own view controller, and that we can cast from a view controller to a specific view controller. My question is about another. Let's simplify this line of code and write it like this:

 " let popup = DatePopupViewController " 

Can we say in this case that we have created an instance of the DatePopupViewController class ?

Comment: You need parentheses to call the initializer: `let popup = DatePopupViewController()`. Then you create an instance `DatePopupViewController`. But if you used a storyboard scene to lay out the `DatePopupViewController`'s view hierarchy, then calling the initializer directly like this will not give good results, because the controller won't know where to find its view hierarchy.

Comment: Okay, let's take this line - " let popup = sb.instantiateInitialViewController() as! DatePopupViewController " - Is the "let popup" an instance of DatePopupViewController class?

Comment: I think the diagram already answers that question.

Comment: Sorry, with all due respect, this definition - "This variable references a UIStoryboard object,  which represents a storyboard at runtime." - is very broad and can be understood in different ways. For example, is this one copy of class, instance of class, or something else?

Comment: You asked about `let popup`. In the diagram, the arrow pointing at `popup` is labeled “This variable gets bounds to the newly-loaded DatePopupViewController.” Isn't that an answer to the question ‘Is the "let popup" an instance of DatePopupViewController class?’

Comment: You wrote - "This variable gets bounds to the newly-loaded DatePopupViewController". That is understandable.
The question is what is the specific way that variable uses to connect with DatePopupViewController?